# After changing permissions to home/ec2-user of the main volume I can no longer SSH in even after changing permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AS the title mentions. I was dumb enough to change the permissions of  `home/ec2-user` recursively to 777 after which I could not log in. I then detached the volume and then attached it to another instance and changed the permission to 700 recursively of that folder. Now when I try to connect to it using the following command I get the error

```
     ssh -v -i  ~/Amazon-fooDev/fooDev.pem ec2-user@ec2-34-212-108-144.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/admin/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-34-212-108-144.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/admin/Amazon-fooDev/fooDev.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/admin/Amazon-fooDev/fooDev.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-34-212-108-144.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:XJWnn7TLa5feJVY7kAOUJQGmWm8J3UNQ/MM+uQZa+Sk
debug1: Host 'ec2-34-212-108-144.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/admin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/admin/Amazon-fooDev/fooDev.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ec2-user@ec2-34-212-108-144.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any suggestions on what I could do to fix this problem. I wasted an entire day trying to connect to that instance and get back to the state it was originally in. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Is 700 permission for `home/ec2-user` correct ? or should i change it to something else ? Do u think I might be looking in the wrong direction ?

Here are a list of some of the latest permissions

```
[root@ip-172-31-42-113 vol1]# chmod 600 home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
[root@ip-172-31-42-113 vol1]# ls -l
total 120
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 17 09:05 bin
dr-xr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Nov 17 09:05 boot
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 28  2014 cgroup
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Aug 11 01:27 dev
drwxr-xr-x 83 root root  4096 Nov 27 01:51 etc
drwx------  3 root root  4096 Nov 17 05:10 home
dr-xr-xr-x  7 root root  4096 Nov 17 08:48 lib
dr-xr-xr-x 10 root root 12288 Nov 17 09:05 lib64
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Aug 11 01:26 local
drwx------  2 root root 16384 Aug 11 01:26 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jan  6  2012 media
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jan  6  2012 mnt
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Aug 11 01:26 opt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Aug 11 01:26 proc
dr-xr-x---  5 root root  4096 Nov 26 12:00 root
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Nov 17 05:10 run
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root root 12288 Nov 17 09:05 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jan  6  2012 selinux
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jan  6  2012 srv
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Aug 11 01:26 sys
drwxrwxrwt  3 root root  4096 Nov 27 03:15 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root  4096 Nov 22 23:12 usr
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root  4096 Nov 17 08:31 var
[root@ip-172-31-42-113 vol1]# cd  home/ec2-user/.ssh/
[root@ip-172-31-42-113 .ssh]# ls -l
total 4
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 391 Nov 27 01:51 authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SSH parameter `-i` expects that the next parameter is the *key name*.

In your case `-iv` tells `ssh` to read the key from file `v` - not quite what you wanted :) The flow-on effect is that the next parameter (the key name) is deemed to be the host name, which it obviously can't resolve.

This will work:

```
ssh -v -i ~/Amazon-Permission/FooDev.pem ec2-user@ec2-...
```

#### Update after your update :)

If you did recursive `chmod 700` it changed the authorized_keys mode too. 
Mount the volume back to your little "helper" instance and do:

```
chmod 600 home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

#### Update 2

Your `home/` must be mode `755` and not `700`. Otherwise `ssh` can't check open the file as `ec2-user`.

```
chmod 755 home
chmod 700 home/ec2-user home/ec2-user/.ssh
chmod 600 home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: @MistyD now you're missing `-i` ...

Comment: sorry. I am so terrible at this DevOps stuff

Comment: @MistyD are you 100% sure it's the correct key?

Comment: @MistyD updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am going to try doing that

Comment: so I updated the permission and put the result in my post. However I am still getting that error

Comment: @MistyD Added Update 2

Comment: AWESOME !!!! Thank you so much that did the trick!!!!!

Comment: @MistyD Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 3):

First, fix the syntax error. You say you used:

```
ssh -iv ~/Amazon-Permission/FooDev.pem ec2-user@ec2-34-212-108-144.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

This tries to load an ssh private key named `v`, which is not what you want. You want the ssh private key named `~/Amazon-Permission/FooDev.pem`. Remove the stray `v` that got in there somehow.

Comment: Yes. I realized that and I removed it

Comment: I just updated my post. I removed the error and put in more details